# Cloudformation:: Condition to the ManagedPolicyArns based on the Environment

Tags: if-statement, aws-cloudformation, fn

I am trying to add a condition to the ManagedPolicyArns based on the environment, it has to run a specify policy

Here's my code:

```
Conditions:
      IsEnvProd: Fn::Equals [!Ref Env, 'prod']

 ManagedPolicyArns:
        - Fn::If:
           - IsEnvProd:
             - "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:policy/prod_policy"
             - "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:policy/stage_policy"
```

Getting the following error:
ValidateTemplate operation: Template error: Fn::If requires a list argument with three elements

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Conditions:
      IsEnvProd: Fn::Equals [!Ref Env, 'prod']

 ManagedPolicyArns:
        - Fn::If:
           - IsEnvProd
           - "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:policy/prod_policy"
           - "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:policy/stage_policy"
```

`Fn::If` takes three parameters. The first one is the condition name, the second is the value if true, and the third is the value if false. You passed a map instead.

Answer (score 0):

Ok that makes sense , thank you:

But I keep getting this error now:

```
Template format error: Conditions can only be boolean operations on parameters and other conditions
```